# Get certificates to expire in one month or less

Tags: powershell, csv, certificate

I want to get all local machine certificates that will expire in one month at maximum and store their information in a `.csv` file. I used this code but it stores also some other certificates that will expire in more than a month.

Here is the code I've written:

```cs
$testPath = 'Cert:\LocalMachine\'
$testDetail = Get-ChildItem -Path $testPath -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.PSIsContainer -ne $true
} | ForEach-Object {
    $DaysLeft = (New-TimeSpan -Start $StartDate -End $_.NotAfter).Days

    $FinalDate = Get-Date $_.NotAfter -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm'
    $Usages = ($_.Extensions | Where-Object {$_.KeyUsages}).KeyUsages
    if ($Usages) {
        # get at most two parts out of the $_.Issuer string
        $issuer = '{0}, {1}' -f ([regex] 'O=([^,]+)').Match($_.Issuer).Groups[1].Value, 
                                ([regex] 'CN=([^,]+)').Match($_.Issuer).Groups[1].Value
        $issuer = $issuer.Trim(", ")

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Issuer             = $issuer.TrimStart('"')
            Usages             = $Usages.ToString() -replace ',', ';'
            Expire_Date        = $FinalDate
            Days_Remaining     = "$DaysLeft"
            Status_Description = "About to expire"
        }
    }
}
$testDetail | Where {
    $_.Days_Remaining -lt 30 -and
    $_.Usages -ne "" 
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path 'C:\SECnology\Data\Files\other1\Certificate_Status.csv'
```

Comment: Just filter for certificates that aren't valid after 30 days from now in the first `Where-Object` filter: `-not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.NotAfter -le (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(30)`.

Comment: @mamadou not sure if you wanted to accept my answer or Ansgar's (we posted in the same time and you accepted very quickly after I posted)

Comment: @robdy It's okay. I deleted my answer since yours provides more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is to filter based on `NotAfter` property. There might be several options based on what exactly you want to achieve:

```bsh
# All certs which expiration date is before Friday, July 19, 2019 00:00:01
# This will include already expired certificates too
$_.NotAfter -le (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(30)

# All certs which expiration date is before Friday, July 19, 2019 00:00:00
# and after Wednesday, June 19, 2019 00:00:00
# This will include certificates that expired today
$_.NotAfter -le (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(30) -and $_.NotAfter -ge (Get-Date).Date
```

General principles:

1. Use `-ge` or `-gt` for specifing start date. The difference is only whether you want to include the exact date or not (so one second of difference)
2. Similarly, use `-le` or `-lt` for specifying end date
3. `(Get-Date)` will give you current date and time, while `(Get-Date).Date)`, today's date at 00:00:00:

```bsh
PS> Get-Date

Wednesday, June 19, 2019 12:16:57

PS> (Get-Date).Date

Wednesday, June 19, 2019 00:00:00
```

Once you clarify the exact conditions, use the rules above to construct your query and add it to your `Where-Object` as [@Ansgar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) mentioned in the comments:

```bsh
Where-Object {
  -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.NotAfter -le (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(30)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Date = ((Get-Date).addmonths(1)).adddays(-(Get-Date ((Get-Date).addmonths(1)) -format dd))
$Certs = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My\ | select *
foreach($Cert in $Certs){
    if($Cert.NotAfter -le $date -and $Cert.NotAfter -ge (Get-Date)){
        $Data =
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Issuer             = $Cert.Issuer
            Expire_Date        = $Cert.NotAfter
            Days_Remaining     = (New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date) -End $($Cert.NotAfter)).Days
            Status_Description = "About to expire"
        }
    }
}
```

Quick small script for you to play around with or get ideas with. This can be run on the 1st of the month and you will get the certs that expire for that month, regardless if the month has 28, 30 or 31 days.

The solution is that you select between the run date and the $_.NotAfter with -le/ge date.